# Why does the following code compile without errors?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, delegates, roslyn, ref

I was messing around with my C# project a little bit and I was surprised to see this code compiles:

```
var a = new Action<string>(ref b => b = "hello");
```

Flipping it the other way around, like `Action<string> a = ref b => b = "hello";` will give a syntactical error at 'ref'.

Sure enough, copy-pasting the snippet into http://dotnetfiddle.net gives a compiler error:

```
A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable
```

Have I encountered a bug in the compiler? (I'm using VS 2015 and C# 6.)

---

**EDIT:** Just switched to the Roslyn compiler on .NET Fiddle, it still emits the same error.

Comment: I tried it at [tryroslyn](http://goo.gl/00ZyS0) and yes: it compiles - the behavior is the same as if `ref` was not there. Looks like a bug (which should possibly be reported if not already done).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Indeed. I've submitted an issue to the [Roslyn GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6646) about this.

Comment: Strange. What about the syntactically correct lambda `(ref string b) => b="hello"` (note the parenthesis and the type `string`), can it be converted to `Action<string>` with that compiler? I do not have access to Visual C# 6 compiler right now.

Comment: ... I tried it with _Try Roslyn_ of @LucasTrzesniewski's link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like a compiler bug in VS2015. This is filed as https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6646

Comment: No, I mean in the compiler for product named "Visual Studio 2015".

Comment: *"It’s an intentional bug that we maintain so as not to break existing code."*. Say what? :-\

Answer (score 0):

i think in first `Action`

> var a = new Action(ref b => b = "hello");

`ref` is reference for complete action `b=>b = "hello"`

while in second

> Action a = ref b => b = "hello";

`ref` is reference for `b` in ref b => b = "hello"

check the below
[fiddle](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayA9HICCpZGD4QAPCgBOkKAD4YVAIwwAvDG2oAZjALnD9iwCIAFqiJE+znLPly7Dz4AdxgSCFQYYLBPGCgwHkiQKnRI1G1tPm0jOioCPkSZPxgFHipsqgAmcxgI0OVVdS1kXWh9MTErWzECCSkzRxq3Dy9nCV9imCK/BQIg0ORgviMrGGTUgDpp2TKKgGYaupgGtU0dPXauuwdrl3dPb3Ht9l2jABZD1HqVU+bWg06Nh6NycMGGDzG40mU1kAF9sLCgAAA==)

Comment: There's no overload of the `Action` constructor that takes a by ref argument, so it should still be an error in the first case.